# brew update not working -- bad substitution error on update.sh

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I just installed OSX El Capitan and started having trouble with Homebrew. First I followed these instructions: https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/10/01/how-i-got-el-capitain-working-with-my-developer-tools/

It didn't help. Then I tried things like changing permissions, doing a hard reset and pulling origin again, uninstalling Homebrew and installing it again, and so on. The error remains. I can run brew doctor and so on, but I can't run brew update (the whole problem started because I ran brew doctor and it recommended that I run brew update). Anyway here's what shows up when I run brew update:

> mv: rename /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-versions, to
>   /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions/homebrew-versions,:
>   No such file or directory /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update.sh:
>   line 58: ${#${tap_dir_basename//[^-]}}: bad substitution

And here's the content of line 58 and the following ones, in update.sh:

```
if [[ ${#${tap_dir_basename//[^\-]}} -gt 1 ]]
then
        echo "Homebrew changed the structure of Taps like <someuser>/<sometap>." >&2
        echo "So you may need to rename $HOMEBREW_LIBRARY/Taps/$user/homebrew-$repo manually." >&2
      fi
    else
      echo "Homebrew changed the structure of Taps like <someuser>/<sometap>. " >&2
      echo "$tap_dir is an incorrect Tap path." >&2
      echo "So you may need to rename it to $HOMEBREW_LIBRARY/Taps/<someuser>/homebrew-<sometap> manually." >&2
    fi
```

I'm out of ideas. Googling it, I found other problems in the same area, but never this exact problem. The others were solved by the actions I already tried. Has anyone seen this before?

EDIT: The issue has been solved. Here's the fix:

```
cd /usr/local
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Comment: If you found a solution for your problem, please add it as an *answer* and "accept" it. This makes sure that your problem is marked as "resolved" by [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the above mentioned answer here to mark as answered:

```
cd /usr/local
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```